# How do you request a named module with requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I think I'm just missing something simple but I've been struggling with requirejs (v2.1.14). Say I have a module defined with a name (perhaps from the r.js optimizer): i.e.

```
// mymodule.js
define("modname", ['dep1', 'dep2', 'dep3'], function(){ ... });
```

If I try to require that module elsewhere it doesn't work.  I've tried using

```
require(['../path/to/file/mymodule'], function(mod){ // mod is undefined here. }
```

which results in mod being undefined, and

```
require(['modname'], function(mod){...}
```

which errors looks for a file named modname.js in the current directory. As soon as I remove the module name part of the define statement from the output then it works fantastically.

```
define(['dep1', 'dep2', 'dep3'], function(mod){ // mod is defined and good here }
```

Am I missing some fundamental piece of requiring named modules??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Require will not know where to look for named modules if they are not in the base directory (or defined in the same file as the require statement), so you need to add a paths entry. You can't use the relative path syntax.

In your config:

```
paths: {
    'modname': 'path/to/mymodule',
},
```

The optimizer uses this to define multiple modules, while keeping them in a single file.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I knew it had to be something simple :)